# What is the correct xsl to replace a part of xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to create some html using a xsl file. Most of it is working fine but I am confused with matching rules for replacing a part of xml. Here is an example, I just need to replace the **secondLine** tag with the xsl rule.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt" ?>
<website>
  <content>
    <b>First Line</b>
    <br/>
    <secondLine/>
    <br/>
    <b>Third Line</b>
  </content>
</website>
```

The xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"
                encoding="utf-8"  />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content/secondLine">
    <b>Second Line</b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current()/node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

It is not really replacing the **secondLine**. I am looking for output like this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<b>First Line</b>
<br/>
<b>Second Line</b>
<br/>
<b>Third Line</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual result you are looking for? -- Hint: your third template prevents your second template from being applied.

Comment: Yes I know the third template is preventing the second template. What I am looking for in all three lines to come in the html file (edited the question with desired output). I tried to change the rules, but one way or other it is not showing the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool to use in situations like these - when you only want to modify parts of the XML input, and leave most of it intact - is the [identity transform template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT), which copies everything as is - unless another template overrides it for (more) specific nodes.

Try the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/website">
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="content/*"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="secondLine">
    <b>Second Line</b>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, it creates two exceptions to the default rule: the first creates the HTML wrappers and skips the existing `content` wrapper; the second replaces the `secondLine` node.

Comment: Thanks... looks logical